# Visual C++ 10 can't start Excel in debug mode

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to build a dll in Visual C++ to be used in Excel VBA. I've done that lots of times but now I'm getting this behaviour I'm stuck with. I start a fresh dll empty project, 
add Excel.exe full path in project->properties->debugging->command, then after starting the debug (F5), Excel won't start (Excel.exe is running but no excel window pops up).

I tried to change the detach options, the debugger type, the .pdb file locations, the type of dll. Before the freeze, I get this pop up that Excel cannot provide with pdb information, which is fine, and then the output stops on *\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL that cannot be found and in the call stack in stuck on ntdll.dll.

Any idea what can be wrong on my new machine?

Thanks, I've been banging my head on the keyboard for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to some help, I found the solution. The debugging was blocked by this EMET (Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit) stuff from Microsoft that was constantly monitoring excel. Once deactivated for Excel, back to normal business.